# When opening text file as table not entire file is saved

Tags: datagrip

After opening a text file larger then 2.5MB, datagrip will open the file in read-only mode. If I then edit the text file as a table and export the table with dump data to file, it will only write the first 2.5MB to file and the rest of the file will never be processed.

How do I make datagrip export the entire file, instead of just the first 2.5mb?

I already tried increasing the file limit in the config, however If I go past the 100mb it requires more then 8GB's of ram to continue.

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry, but there is no workaround for now. Can you please describe the whole task? Perhaps I can help you.

Comment: I've got a lot of CSV files with are using an incorrect syntax depending on the file. So I would normally open them in datagrip, then edit as table and export to a mysql server(Now it will do the entire file), but that is incredibly slow. So I would export it as a proper syntax csv then use the mysql import command which is a lot faster than the way datagrip inports the data.